# OKTA multi-factor authentication + Java + RestAssured: /login/step-up/redirect always returns 403 through RESTAssured

Tags: java, rest-assured, okta, okta-api, multi-factor-authentication

I am attempting to authenticate into OKTA using Java's RestAssured API. The authentication type in question is multi-factor, and while I am always able to get this authentication to succeed in Google Chrome, it consistently fails in RestAssured with a 403 despite matching all of the request headers and cookies. My end goal is to get the bearer authentication token in order to be able to run services after I login.

Essentially, this is the sequence of services I'm calling:

1) [redacted]/api/v1/authn; I provide my username and password, as well as some alphanumeric state token. (I use a wrapper class around RestAssured's RequestSpecification:) This returns successfully with a 200:

```
            // Create a brand new request to login using OKTA.
        RequestWrapper requestWrapper11 = new RequestWrapper();
        requestWrapper11.setResponseContentType(ContentType.JSON);
        requestWrapper11.setAcceptedContentType(ContentType.JSON);
        requestWrapper11.setHTTPMethod(Method.POST);

        requestWrapper11.setRequestPayload(new HashMap<>() {
            {
                put("username", "[redacted]");
                put("password", "[redacted]");
                put("options", new HashMap<String, Object>() {
                    { put("warnBeforePasswordExpired", true); }
                    { put("multiOptionalFactorEnroll", true); }
                });
            }
        });

        // Authenticate and get a brand new state token.
        requestWrapper11.setBaseURL(new URL("[redacted]/api/v1/authn"));
        ResponseWrapper response = requestWrapper11.executeAndGetResponse();
```

From this service call, I get back a state token that I use in the next step, as well as a factor ID.

2) I then call the POST service [redacted]/api/v1/authn/factors and provide the answer to the security question: (this also returns successfully with a 200):

{answer: "[redacted_1]", stateToken: "[state_token]"}

```
     RequestWrapper requestWrapper2 = new RequestWrapper();
        requestWrapper2.setResponseContentType(ContentType.JSON);
        requestWrapper2.setAcceptedContentType(ContentType.JSON);
        requestWrapper2.setHTTPMethod(Method.POST);

        requestWrapper2.setRequestPayload(new HashMap<>() {
            {
                put("answer", "[redacted]");
                put("stateToken", stateToken);
            }
        });
        requestWrapper2.setOverrideQueryParams(new HashMap<>() {
            { put("rememberDevice", false); }
        });

        // Authenticate and get a brand new state token.
        requestWrapper2.setBaseURL(new URL("[redacted]/api/v1/authn/factors/" + factorId + "/verify"));
```

3) Finally, I make a GET call [redacted]/login/step-up/redirect?stateToken=[state_token] to return a special code used for authentication purposes.

```
        RequestWrapper requestWrapper4 = new RequestWrapper();
        // requestWrapper4.setAllowRedirects(true);
        requestWrapper4.setOverrideQueryParams(new HashMap<>() {
            {put("stateToken",stateToken); }
        });
        requestWrapper4.setHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        requestWrapper4.setHeader("Host", "[redacted]");
        requestWrapper4.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml" +
                ";q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9");
        requestWrapper4.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        requestWrapper4.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
        requestWrapper4.setHeader("Sec-Fetch-Dest","document");
        requestWrapper4.setHeader("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "navigate");
        requestWrapper4.setHeader("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-origin");
        requestWrapper4.addCookies(responseWrapper2.cookies);
        requestWrapper4.addCookie("oktaStateToken", stateToken);
        requestWrapper4.addCookie("t", "summer");
        requestWrapper4.addCookie("DT", "DI0--aZ4ipPS8mFXhEWHFwXUw");
        requestWrapper4.addCookie("ADRUM_BTa", "R:0|g:dd262b5c-ae86-4a1d-86aa-a89b3fed2bed|n:Okta_6d5b1e30-d05a-4894-a37b-81b5f6c60e0e");
        requestWrapper4.addCookie("ADRUM_BT1", "R:0|i:617|e:41");
        requestWrapper4.setHTTPMethod(Method.GET);
        requestWrapper4.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.113 Safari/537.36");
        requestWrapper4.setBaseURL(new URL("[redacted]/login/step-up/redirect"));
        ResponseWrapper responseWrapper4 = requestWrapper4.executeAndGetResponse();
```

When I authenticate in normally using the browser, these three service calls are made in the browser without issue and all return 200 or 302. However, whenever I run these using the RestAssured API, I always get a 403 on the third service executed, regardless of whether the token passed in as the query parameter {stateToken} is legitimate or not. I always get 400 when this parameter isn't passed in through the RestAssured API, so I know that this method call distinguishes between whether a state token is passed in or not.

My question is: is there anything notable that I'm missing from the set of steps above to cause a 403 to always be returned through one medium but not through a web browser? Is there something in place to prevent authentication using the RestAssured API? If so, is there another route I could take to get the bearer token?

Comment: Have you tried to replicate this with POSTMAN ? If you get the same error in POSTMAN then we can rule out the possibility that Rest Assured is the one creating the problem, and if you get a success in POSTMAN then we can compare the traffic details side by side. I would also advice you to include a `log().all()` in your Rest Assured test to see the complete traffic details

Comment: I've just tried twice using POSTMAN, and it yields the same result: a 403.

Comment: So its not with Rest Assured, 1 ) Either the API is not working as expected or 2 ) You are not testing it right. 403 is from the 4xx series stating that the requested resource is forbidden for some reason. If you can get it working through POSTMAN then there's no trouble getting it to work using RA

Comment: I suspect it may have something to do with the state token. I've noticed in the web browser when the first step is called, that the state token is generated prior to that step, but I have been unable to recover that token prior to step 1. Rather, I am executing step 1 and a state token is generated from that particular step. I've read up that there are strict requirements on the state of the state token, explaining why it failed in Step 3.

Answer (score 0):

I few things come to mind.

1.) Does your response contain the step up link in response #2?
https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/authn/#response-example-after-authentication-and-mfa-are-complete-for-step-up-authentication-with-okta-session

2.) If possible I'd recommend an OAuth flow (or SAML) instead of using the Authn API

3.) The Authn API is a state machine, you cannot always assume that you can execute those requests in that order.

Okta also has an Authn SDK: https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-java (but again, we recommend OAuth when possible)